# Azure SDK: What PublicClientApplicationBuilder class is for? Microsoft doc does not give a definition

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

When developing a `.NET Core` app using [Azure SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net), I am trying to understand [PublicClientApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplicationbuilder?view=azure-dotnet) class. The official linked document does not define what this class does. The doc has only given its methods. An online search does not provide a definition either. **Question**: What does this class do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It instantiates a public client application in Azure AD, e.g. use [`Build()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplicationbuilder.build?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_PublicClientApplicationBuilder_Build) like below.

```
IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .Build();
```

It returns [`IPublicClientApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.ipublicclientapplication?view=azure-dotnet), then you can use the [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.ipublicclientapplication?view=azure-dotnet#methods) to do something e.g. get the access token.

This sample below uses an interactive way to get the token for Micrsoft Graph via the logged user:

```
var scopes = new List<string>() { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var token = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

Reference - [Initialize client applications using MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-initializing-client-applications)

Comment: Your [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-initializing-client-applications) link helped understand the purpose of the class (thank you): `With MSAL.NET 3.x, the recommended way to instantiate an application is by using the application builders: PublicClientApplicationBuilder and ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.`